# Trigger azure pipeline when a new package is available in a feed

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am attempting to trigger an azure pipeline using yaml when a new package is available in a feed inside azure artifacts. There is [documentation](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/blob/master/design/pipeline-resources.md) indicating that you can trigger a pipeline when a new package is available.

```
 resources:        # types: pipelines | builds | repositories | containers | packages
  packages:
  - package: string   # identifier for the package resource
    type: string   # the type of your package like Nuget, NPM etc.
    connection: string   # service connection for your package repo.
    package: string   # package definition
    version: string   # optional; the version of the package to download, defaults to latest published vession.
    tag: string   # optional; branch to pick the artifact; defaults to master branch
```

My package type is 'upack'. My pipeline and feed are in the same project. I tried to trigger the pipeline with below code.

```
resources:
  packages:
    - package: 'package-release' 
      type: 'upack'
      name: 'feedname'
      trigger: true
```

Th pipe line execution shows the error "No artifact type found corresponding to ID upack". Is this package type not supported? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `resources` will give you access to the package but wont trigger the pipeline. Are you generating the feed with another devops piepline ? you could trigger your pipeline when the pipeline creating the package is finished tho

Comment: Yes. Feed is generated from another dev ops pipeline and this is in another organization. I can't access parent pipeline from child pipe line through service connection due to security reasons.

Comment: Have you tried this approach: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops#configure-pipeline-resource-triggers ? Are these pipeline in the same devops project / organization ?

Comment: Parent pipeline is in Organization1/Project1 and child pipeline is in Organization2/Project2. As per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops#configure-pipeline-resource-triggers, I have to access pipeline and repo of Organization1/Project1 from Organization2/Project2. This approach is not suitable in my case as Organization2 is client and not allowed any external service connection from there..

Comment: you could run your pipeline on schedule `every x minutes/hours` and if there is a new version of the package in the feed, run additional tasks ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: Or you could have a look at webhooks: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/services/webhooks?view=azure-devops ?

Comment: how did you manage to solve this?